# How do I display this json file correctly in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to create a Store page for my website.  I want to display the following json file in ng-repeat:

```js
{
  "cupcakes": {
      "Vanilla": [
          {"price":"9.99", "stock":"20", "amount":"8",
          "ingredients":"flour, sugar, vanilla extract",
          "popular":true}
      ],
      "Maple": [
          {"price":"9.99", "stock":"15", "amount":"8", 
          "ingredients":"flour, sugar, maple syrup",
          "popular":true}
      ]
  },
  "cookies": {
      "Vanilla": [
          {"price":"7.99", "stock":"50", "amount":"12", "ingredients":"flour, sugar, vanilla extract"}
      ],
      "Maple": [
          {"price":"7.99", "stock":"50", "amount":"12", "ingredients":"flour, sugar, maple syrup"}
      ]
  }
}
```

I want to display the type item (cupcake or cookie) then the type of each item (vanilla or maple) then the unique attributes and be able to filter and search through them.  I'm thinking I may have to restructure my json file, but I'm not sure.  Should I sort out the items ahead of time in my controller with a forEach?  Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('root', [])
.controller("index", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = null;
    $scope.email = null;
    $scope.comments = null;
    $scope.reason = null;
    $scope.employees = [];
    $scope.items = [];


    $http.get('http://localhost:8000/employees.json').then(function(result) {
        $scope.employees = result.data.records;
    });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8000/inventory.json').then(function(result) {
        $scope.items = result.data;
    });

    $scope.isEnabled = function() {
        if ($scope.name && $scope.email && $scope.comments) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, almost everything is an array. You can iterate over an array of objects or, in an object you are iterating over his properties.

The following script should do the work.

```
<div ng-repeat="(itemLabel, itemValue)in items">
     {{itemLabel}}
     <div ng-repeat="(flavorLabel, flavorValue)in itemValue">
         {{flavorLabel}}
         <div ng-repeat="object in flavorValue">
             <div ng-repeat="property in object">
                 {{property}}
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fpnsd8n/)

Comment: On second thought this doesn't work if I want to add more data to the json file.  I think it has to do with the ng-repeat tag.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind I fixed the issue by removing the 4th no-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way for showing your data using `ng-repeat`:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(foodKey, foodVal) in foods">
     <b>{{foodKey}}</b>
      <div ng-repeat="(typesKey, typesVal) in foodVal">
          <span>{{typesKey}}</span>
          <ul ng-repeat="types in typesVal">
              <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in types">
                  {{key}} : {{val}}
              </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course it will only work if `foods` is the json you posted in your answer.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LonLceje/).

For more information on `ng-repeat` see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 1):

Just going through your JSON.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in inventory">{{key}}
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(material_key, material_value) in value">{{material_key}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(options_key, options_value) in material_value[0]">{{options_key}} - {{options_value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
```

Have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UXNFYA1Ah4jOpBhTAkgh?p=preview). I hope this will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need multiple `ng-repeaters`  hope this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJGOM98n8bMNPTMWEAKj?p=preview) is your requirement

Answer (score -1):

you can do anything with the keys of your JSON in javascript , by converting the JSON to object by

```
JSON.parse(json);
```

later on you can access any key and that will be an object/hashmap to loop or sort

So in your case, your API result can be parsed like

```
var resultData = JSON.parse(result.data);
```

Later you can do ng-repeat in your view some thing like

```
[{id: 'foo'}, {id: 'bar'}] | orderBy:'id'
```